# How to subset a Pandas dataframe applying a function by date?

Tags: python, pandas

This is a simplified version of my data:

```
Date and Time           Price   Volume
2015-01-01 17:00:00.211 2030.25 342
2015-01-01 17:00:02.456 2030.75 725
2015-01-01 17:00:02.666 2030.75 203
2015-01-02 17:00:00.074 2031.00 101
2015-01-02 17:00:16.221 2031.75 245
2015-01-02 17:00:25.882 2031.75 100
2015-01-03 17:00:00.054 2031.00 180
2015-01-03 17:00:25.098 2031.75 849
2015-01-03 17:00:45.188 2031.75 549
```

I would like subset the dataframe selecting the min of the column 'Volume' **each day**, with the corresponding 'Date and Time' and 'Price'. The output would be:

```
Date and Time           Price   Volume
2015-01-01 17:00:02.666 2030.75 203
2015-01-02 17:00:25.882 2031.75 100
2015-01-03 17:00:00.054 2031.00 180
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is if you separate the `Date` and `Time` into two separate columns. As you said in your post you need "*min of the column 'Volume' each day*".

```
    Date        Time            Price    Volume
0   2015-01-01  17:00:00.211    2030.25     342
1   2015-01-01  17:00:02.456    2030.75     725
2   2015-01-01  17:00:02.666    2030.75     203
3   2015-01-02  17:00:00.074    2031.00     101
4   2015-01-02  17:00:16.221    2031.75     245
5   2015-01-02  17:00:25.882    2031.75     100
6   2015-01-03  17:00:00.054    2031.00     180
7   2015-01-03  17:00:25.098    2031.75     849
8   2015-01-03  17:00:45.188    2031.75     549

df = df.groupby('Date')['Volume'].min()
print (df)
```

The output is the minimum of the column `Volume` each day.

```
Date
2015-01-01    203
2015-01-02    100
2015-01-03    180
Name: Volume, dtype: object
```

**EDIT** : If you want to also get the indices of the original DataFrame (*corresponding Time and the Price*) you can do this instead:

```
idx = df.groupby(['Date'])['Volume'].transform(min) == df['Volume']
df[idx]
```

In this case the output:

```
    Date        Time            Price    Volume
2   2015-01-01  17:00:02.666    2030.75     203
5   2015-01-02  17:00:25.882    2031.75     100
6   2015-01-03  17:00:00.054    2031.00     180
```

Comment: I need to include the Time and the Price corresponding to that 'Volume' min, for each day, as in the model output in my question. How would I do that?

Comment: @hernanavella I edited my answer to include the Time and the Price corresponding to the min 'Volume'. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Group the rows by day, then get the row with the minimum Volume, for each day:

```
from pandas import DatetimeIndex, DataFrame

df = DataFrame(...)
times = DatetimeIndex(df['Date and Time'])
grouped = df.groupby([times.day])

# takes DataFrame as input; returns the DataFrame row with the lowest 'Volume'
find_min = lambda cur_df: cur_df.ix[cur_df['Volume'].idxmin()]
# assemble a DataFrame from Series objects
result = DataFrame([find_min(x[1]) for x in grouped])
result = result.reset_index(drop=True)   # optional re-indexing

print result
```

The output:

```
             Date and Time    Price Volume
0  2015-01-01 17:00:02.666  2030.75    203
1  2015-01-02 17:00:25.882  2031.75    100
2  2015-01-03 17:00:00.054  2031.00    180
```

Comment: I only need the Volume Column min. Your solution gives me the min for every column.  Compare it with the output model in my question.